# install4j sql script action statement with line breaks

Tags: sql, install4j

a problem with the SQL script action: I use a script with statements including line breaks to make them more readable. I use the semicolon as a statement delimter. When the action fires, the first statement (fired vs an Oracle DB in the example) fails with a "ORA-00904: : invalid identifier" message, showing only the first line of the statement in the installation log.
The statement itself is valid.
My assumption is that install4j fires each line within an sql script, not the whole text (multiple lines) until a statement delimiter is found?
Would be a pity, since long statements tend to be not easy to read.
We are using instll4j 6.1.6 build 6352, the instaler runs under windows (x64).

Thanks a lot for your help in advance,
regards,
Alex

Comment: Help me help you - show your code.

Comment: What "code" do you mean? The install4j-xml? The sql scripts?
Specific SQL-Code would only confuse, the problem is clearly described.
Anyway, looks like it works without line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the line breaks within the sql script, it worked.
So currently no line breaks in SQL-Scripts, except they are used as statement delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

install4j 6.1.6 seems to have a problem with the ExecuteSqlScriptAction.

The SQL statement returns with an error, that looks like only the first character of the provided script is executed as an SQL script, e.g. "d" instead of "drop user test cascade". ORA-00900 invalid statement.

Downgrading to 6.1.5 resolved the problem.